# View contents of my documents directory

Tags: iphone

I need to verify the correct function of an application I am working with, and can see that the files are being written properly to the users documents directory in the simulator.

I need to verify airplane mode, so either I need to be able to see into the documents directory on the phone or put the simulator in airplane mode.

I thought that there was a way to view the contents of the phone in the Organizer, but have had no luck.

Does anyone have an idea on the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Organizer, when your device is selected, your applications should appear in a list at the bottom of the window. Next to any application you've installed via Xcode, there should be a disclosure triangle. Click this, and your user folders will be revealed. Just drag the small package icon to your desktop to copy them to your computer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I knew I had seen this somewhere before.

Comment: Exactly what I needed also, thanks!! I would have never figured this out

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wondering where this is ... look at this screenshot.

Its in your Xcode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 9:

- Window/Devices
- Select your device
- Select your app
- Click the option wheel and select "Download container". Then right-click on that file and Open Packages.

"Show container" (or double-click on the application) didn't work for me, it showed an empty list.